# how to use a while loop to keep asking for input until the input is correct (C)?

Tags: c, loops, input

I want to use a while loop to keep asking the user for the right input until it is given. Is this possible with scanf()? I know that if the input does not match, it is left unassigned and is saved to be captured by the second scanf().

The following program runs on forever and does not ask me for my second input when the first input is wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
/* Check the input, if the input does not contain a single integer value, 
then keep asking for the integer value */
/* I used a counter variable so that the program does not run on forever */
int
main (int argc, char * argv[]){
    int counter = 10, items = 0, input = 0;
    while (counter){
        printf("input an integer value: ");
         items = scanf("%d",&input);
         if (items == 1){
             printf("successfully read an item");
             break;
         }   
         else{
             counter --;
             input = 0;
             printf("failed to read an item, please try again\n");
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: from what I can tell the issue seems to be that scanf is not pausing to read a second input after being called a second time. Not sure how to solve that problem atm but I think that is the real issue OP is running into

Comment: try pressing Ctrl-D rather than just return

Comment: If it is running on forever that likely means your file stream has an error and may need to be cleared.

Comment: So i just made a test case: `int     main(void)
{
        int input;

        printf("A");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        printf("B");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        printf("C");
}
` and I think a simplified question of OP is: how do I get scanf to trigger a second time after an invalid input is given the first time

Comment: Have you tried flushall() after reading your variable?

Comment: This exact (flawed) attempt is covered in my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) which you might want to read. In a nutshell, `scanf()` is for parsing, not reading; when it can't parse it doesn't read either, so it just leaves stuff in the input buffer. Better loop with e.g. `fgets()` and then parse that line with `atoi()`, `strtol()`, `strtod()`, `sscanf()` etc.

Comment: @someone_smiley This comment is dangerous. `flushall()` isn't even standard C and the often seen `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the infinite loop is due to a bad scanf call which returns 0 if nothing is read, or EOF if there is an error.  Regardless the non integer item on the stream is never taken off, so the scanf call keeps returning the same 0 value since it can't proceed until it is removed or jumped past (per other answers here).

One way to get around this is to clear the buffer.  Here's one way to go about it.

```
char tmp;
...
items = scanf("%d",&input);    
if(items!=1){
  // perhaps printf('That was not a number\n');
  while(scanf('%c',&tmp)!=EOF);
}
else if(items==1){
   ... //hooray you read an item, it's value is in input
}
else{
      // the user quit with a Control-D or something.
}
```

p.s. I like the [reference by Felix](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) on how to get away from scanf.

Comment: A `scanf` doesn't return `EOF` if it can't read a number. If would return 0 in this case. You can check if `items ! = 1`

Comment: Your alternative check is fine, but the comment about scanf is incorrect. 
 Per the reference [manual](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html#scanf):  On success the number of input fields converted and stored are returned. If an input failure occurred, then EOF is returned.

Comment: It's tripped me up a number of times.

Comment: @information Yes! That is if input failure occurred. Meaning some one pressed Ctr+D on the input, or the input file is finished. But if there is content and it can't be parsed as integer, it wont return EOF, it will return 0.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya You're right.  See, I get tripped up by that still.  Thanks for the feedback.  I'll update the post too.

Answer (score -3):

ok so after some testing and searching I found you can use `fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);` to solve your problem.

try:

```
#include<stdio.h>
/* Check the input, if the input does not contain a single integer value,
   then keep asking for the integer value */
/* I used a counter variable so that the program does not run on forever */
int
main (int argc, char * argv[]){
        int counter = 10, items = 0, input = 0;
        while (counter){
                printf("input an integer value: ");
                items = scanf("%d",&input);
                if (items == 1){
                        printf("successfully read an item");
                        break;
                }
                else{
                        counter --;
                        input = 0;
                        printf("failed to read an item, please try again\n");
                        fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `stdin` is not guaranteed to support positioning requests, and hence `fseek(stdin, ...)` may fail.